# Control speed of motor with an AVR through a ESC

Tags: avr, motor-controller

I have a [XRotor 40A ESC](http://www.hobbywing.com/product_show.asp?id=326) and I started working on controlling it with an AVR micro. I have connected everything: motor, battery and ESC, and connected the ESC input wire to the micro.

The code on the micro is written by my co-worker and it's working to drive a SG-90 servo.

I started testing this afternoon but it seems that the motor does not want to work properly, only beep beep (with a very tiny movement).

Comment: Please add a schematic. It's difficult to understand how you have connected everything without one.

Comment: Or migrate the question to psychics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electronic speed control AKA brushless motor driver for RC models receives its throttle input as a pulse width modulated signal. To control the throttle you must provide it a square wave with a pulse length (AKA high time) between 1 and 2 milliseconds, and a period of 20 milliseconds.

[image: RC PWM]

A high time of 1 ms means "motor off", while a high time of 2 ms means "full speed". RC servos are controlled in the same manner, where at 1 ms it rotates to one extreme, at 1.5 ms it is centered and at 2ms it's at the other extreme position.

The ESC will beep when initially given power. In order to prevent the motor from running accidentally, the ESC implements a safeguard where it must be "armed" by first giving zero throttle, then full throttle and finally zero throttle before it will spin the motor. Immediately after the ESC has been armed, it will beep again in a different way for confirmation.

Do you have the ESC servo connector ground wire (usually black) connected to the arduino ground? Just hooking up the signal wire is not enough, the current needs a return path.

The motor twitches when beeping because the ESC uses the brushless motor coils as a crude speaker.

You really should read about RC components so that you actually know what you are doing. This site is not RC- oriented, you should ask these kinds of questions at e.g. http://rcgroups.com, https://reddit.com/r/radiocontrol/.

Comment: Wow. I don't think it's a process. I saw some calibrating and startup process in the manual but thought there aren't for my case. It says: "Turn on the transmitter and move the throttle stick to bottom the motor will emit a long beep, after that system  is ready to go."

Comment: Most modern ESCs only require going to low throttle for arming (not low-high-low), but you should read your ESC's instruction manual to confirm. Some ESCs require throttle calibration before first use, typically by starting at **high** throttle then going to low throttle after the motor makes a few beeps. Once again, read the manual to find what out _your_ ESC needs!

Comment: @BruceAbbott True, it's specific to the ESC. The sequence I described is apparently in the minority:  my littlebee ESCs (BLheli firmware) expect a low - mid(not high) - low arming sequence, while my turnigy red brick ESC behaves as you described.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. The motor spins but not accurately, it rapidly rotate back and forth and the wire and the motor get hot.

Comment: @SAMPro You either have only two motor wires connected to the ESC out of three, you have destroyed some of the ESC output MOSFETs, or you have a damaged motor. If you use mounting screws that are too long they will screw right into the motor coils damaging the insulation and shorting the windings to themselves or to the stator.

Comment: We test with another motor and worked perfectly. After several investigating find out the red wire is not soldered well to the socket cause motor misbehaving. Thanks a lot.